# JAX-WS + Spring : force CDATA on some inputs

Tags: java, xml, spring, jax-ws, cdata

I currently have a problem using Spring + JAX-WS. I have a method with @Webmethod, which returns a custom object. In this object, there are some String fields that may contain some HTML...

The XML produced is good, except when there is HTML in one of the fields, so I'm trying to add a cdata node to prevent escaping, but it doesn't succeed :(

I tried adding @XmlCDATA using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html), but it seems to have no effects.

There is also a strange thing, sometimes a CDATA node is added automatically, without changing anything, but with the same string duplicated twice and concatened, or with a part of the string (eg "The sentence" => "The sentence The sentence"), the CDATA node is not present anymore. I can't determine when the CDATA is added, or why it is'nt added every time, it seems to be random (but of course I think it's not).

Anyone has a suggestion on how to force the CDATA node in Spring (annotations, xml config, other...) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add CDATA or properly encode your HTML before adding it to the XML.

I'd wonder why you need to send HTML (client side stuff) to a SOAP service.  Could be a bad design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This is not really HTML, just some text stored in the database that is sent to a mobile app through a call to the WS, but the text can contains some HTML elements such as <br> or <p>, that have to be interpreted properly... 
I already tried to add "<![CDATA[" + string + "]]>" but in some case there are 2 cdata nodes because of the stange thing happening in some case (see first post).
Encoding the HTML might be a solution, I will think about it

Comment: I would say those sound like CSS items that would be better handled by styling outside the content.

Comment: No, there is absolutely no CSS, just some text, and in some cases text with some basic HTML elements

Comment: Not your fault; I think everyone would prefer that they not exist, because they are style.  CSS didn't exist then.  You ought to rethink moving them out of your response sent to the mobile device.

Comment: ? I just said there is no CSS items in the text... Even if there was, it should not be interpreted because there is no < or > ?

Comment: I understand.  <b> == bold, which you could turn into a <div class="x"> and CSS class name.  Same with <p> - <div> with style for positioning.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, but in my example that was a <br/> and not <b>, but anyway you're right, it is possible there is some attributes int the HTML tags... Will try encoding the HTML, thanks for your help